# In ADF, I am not able to define the "Response body definition" in REST call (ExternalCall) in Mapping data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3byO.png)

[MY CURRENT PIPELINE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3byO.png)

and I am trying to make an external call to my API which is an azure functions and the response of the API looks like

```html
[
    {
        "customerTaxCountryCode": "CODE1",
        "customerTaxLocalName": "TAXLOCAL1",
        "customerTaxNumber": "TAX00023",
        "customerTaxCountry": "USA",
        "customerTaxTypeCode": "TAXNO1"
    },
    {
        "customerTaxCountryCode": "CODE2",
        "customerTaxLocalName": "TAXLOCAL2",
        "customerTaxNumber": "TAX9544",
        "customerTaxCountry": "USA",
        "customerTaxTypeCode": "TAXNO2"
    }
]
```

I tried importing the schema by clicking Import Projection, but it is giving the irrelevant response

[error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjezh.png)

I tried writing the complex structure as ,

```html
(customerTaxTypeCode as string, customerTaxCountryCode as string, customerTaxLocalName as string, customerTaxNumber as string, customerTaxCountry as string )[]
```

[not getting mapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD1oY.png)

still, the data is not getting mapped.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right approach.

To read the data from API, you need to use [`Web activity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) to fetch the data.

Use `@activity('Web1').output.Response` expression at second web activity to save the output as a blob to the container.

[image]

Once data stored in blob storage, you can create a linked service for it and read the data in `data flow` activity and then you can transform it easily.